# Do Worker manager wakes up if App receives notification in Android?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-service, alarmmanager, job-scheduling

I'm seeing spike is api calls hit when I send push notifications to user(But I don't trigger any api calls when I receive notification). I do have worker manager to sync data in case of offline usage/failure in download. Worker manager have constraint on network connected and nothing else.

I have a hypothesis that worker manager triggers(if not started) when app receives push notification, is it right? If not what can be other ways which can cause this issue.

Note :

1. There are no api calls on receiving notification.
2. No network calls in Application class